# How to display the following UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, gmsmapview

I have the following setup on one of my pages:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K94Dr.jpg

The current page displays a mapView with Google Maps and I pretend to display the UIView on top of the mapView... I've tried anything but the mapView always displays on top of the UIView. How can I fix this?

This is my page code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces

class GoogleMapPage: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!
    var addressName: String? = nil
    lazy var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    var latitude: Double = 0.0
    var longitude: Double = 0.0


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sideMenu: UIView!


    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestLocation()
        placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()

        mapView.bringSubviewToFront(cameraButton)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
        if let location = locations.first {
            createMap(location.coordinate.longitude, location.coordinate.latitude)
            self.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
            self.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(okayAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func createMap(_ longitude: Double, _ latitude: Double){
        let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, zoom: 12.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        marker.map = mapView
        marker.title = "Your Position"
        mapView.addSubview(cameraButton)
        mapView.addSubview(menuButton)

        view = mapView

        let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

        // Geocode Location
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
            // Process Response
            print(placemarks as Any)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are adding MenuView and buttons inside MapView, not top off the map view. MenuView is subview of Mapview thats why it is not showing

Comment: I thought about it too. But when I try to put them out they are forced to go inside the mapview... Any idea why?

Comment: Use Document coloumn on left side  showing in the image you posted. Drag menuview outside of Mapview showing under "Google Maps Page"

Comment: I tried that but he only allows me to put the side menu below the first responder and that puts the piece out of the screen.

Comment: Try adding it above Mapview. And then in your viewwillappear function write view.bringSubviewToFront(sideMenu)